# Perl hash giving undef values

Tags: perl, perl-hash

If was trying to write a piece of code using `perl hash`. There are no undefined values  or new lines in `__DATA__`(tried giving same input from file also). But while printing using data dumper or the traditional way I am getting a `''` as key and `undef` as its value. Why is this happening ? Am I missing something obvious ?

Program:

```
use strict;
use Data::Dumper;

my %i_hash = undef;
my %p_hash = undef;

while (<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    my @line = split(/\h+/);
    $i_hash{ $line[0] } = $line[1];    # Interactions Hash
    $p_hash{ $line[0] } = $line[2];    # PMIDs Hash

}
print Dumper( \%i_hash, \%p_hash );

__DATA__
AAA     BBB     PMID_1
BBB     AAA     PMID_2
CCC     AAA     PMID_3
DDD     CCC     PMID_4
EEE     FFF     PMID_1
FFF     GGG     PMID_6
```

OutPut:

```
$VAR1 = {
      '' => undef,
      'FFF' => 'GGG',
      'CCC' => 'AAA',
      'BBB' => 'AAA',
      'EEE' => 'FFF',
      'DDD' => 'CCC',
      'AAA' => 'BBB'
    };
$VAR2 = {
      '' => undef,
      'FFF' => 'PMID_6',
      'CCC' => 'PMID_3',
      'BBB' => 'PMID_2',
      'EEE' => 'PMID_1',
      'DDD' => 'PMID_4',
      'AAA' => 'PMID_1'
    };
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Always use `use warnings;`!

```
my %i_hash = undef;
my %p_hash = undef;
```

gives

```
Odd number of elements in hash assignment at a.pl line 6.
Use of uninitialized value in list assignment at a.pl line 6.
Odd number of elements in hash assignment at a.pl line 7.
Use of uninitialized value in list assignment at a.pl line 7.
```

You didn't provide a value for the value element, so `undef` is used after issuing a warning.

Keys are strings and the stringification of `undef` is the empty string, though doing so issues a warning.

You want:

```
my %i_hash;
my %p_hash;
```

Comment: Thanks, It's Working. I generally use that syntax for initializing Arrays and Scalars. I used the same for hash. BTW when can I use this kind of syntax.

Comment: Bad idea for arrays too. `my @array = undef;` is the same thing as `my @array; $array[0] = undef;`. And it's simply useless noise for scalars. It's wrong across the board.

Comment: @aravindramesh, please note that when you type `my @array = undef; if ( @array ) {print 'true';}` the 'if' statement will be true here, because your array already has 1 element (undef). you will be surprised, but you should not to return undef from subs too, because `my @ar = f(); if ( @ar ) {print 'true';} sub f{return undef;}` 'if' will be true here for same reason